# Preparing two MediaPlayers in the same activity

Tags: android

I would like to prepare two MediaPlayers in the same activity. I buffer mp3 from net and becouse it takes some time, my idea to speed it up was: when first sample is playing, the second is preparing.

Unfortunately I can't make it work. That is method for buffering:

```
    private void getMusic(MediaPlayer player, String url) {

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.prepareAsync();          
}
```

And this is onPrepared method.

```
    @Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {

    preparedEnd=true;
    prepareState++;
    player.start();
    if(prepareState==1)
        getMusic(player2, "some_url");
}
```

I thought that if player would be prepared, I could use prepareAsync() again. I tried some others ideas, but no one helped. The problem is with prepareAsync(), becouse when I used prepare() there weren't any problems.

That's my errors:

```
05-23 01:35:22.848: E/MediaPlayer(29894): prepareAsync called in state 1
05-23 01:35:22.858: D/AndroidRuntime(29894): Shutting down VM
05-23 01:35:22.858: W/dalvikvm(29894): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab0228)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crivline.musicGame/com.crivline.musicGame.NewGame}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepareAsync(Native Method)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(MediaPlayer.java:1357)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.crivline.musicGame.NewGame.getMusic(NewGame.java:460)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.crivline.musicGame.NewGame.selectPlayer(NewGame.java:427)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.crivline.musicGame.NewGame.prepareMediaPlayer(NewGame.java:413)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.crivline.musicGame.NewGame.getData(NewGame.java:270)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at com.crivline.musicGame.NewGame.onCreate(NewGame.java:125)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
05-23 01:35:22.868: E/AndroidRuntime(29894):    ... 11 more
```

THANKS A LOT FOR HELP IN ADVANCE!

Comment: the problem is showing for the first one or for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that with @Pesal's help. The correct code:

```
    MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp1.setDataSource("source1");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp2.setDataSource("source2");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mp1.prepareAsync();

    mp2.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mp2.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the same name for both media players. What's going on here is you start a playback so your MediaPlayer player is in .start() state, when you get another MediaPlayer the mediaplayer gets the same name player and goes to .prepare() state. Android MediaPlayer doesn't allow you to go directly from start to prepare again. You have to first stop before you prepare.

Here is the solution:
Create two MediaPlayers:

```
    MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer mp2 = new MediaPlayer();

    mp1.setDataSource(yoururl);
    mp2.setDataSource(nexturl);

    mp1.preapareAsync();
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp1) {

    mp1.start();
    }
    mp2.prepare();
    mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
```

Check the mediaplayer flow diagram here to see which states are posible to move from one to another
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: I prepared two different MediaPlayer instances, but I induced them from the same method. Your code is almost correct, eclipse can't debug "mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2)".

Below I paste the correct code to fix this. 

Thanks a lot for help!